# Unable to map from one ViewModel to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm making a list of checkboxes to update a user's roles, and I'm trying to map from this:

```
public class ApplicationRoleViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedName { get; set; }
    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; } // Font Awesome-ikoner, f.eks. "fa-user"
}
```

to this:

```
public class SelectableRoleViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

This is my mapping:

```
CreateMap<ApplicationRoleViewModel, SelectableRoleViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, s => s.MapFrom(i => i.Id))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DisplayName, s => s.MapFrom(d => d.DisplayName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Selected, i => i.Ignore());
```

Mapping it like this in the controller:

```
ApplicationRole role = await db.Roles.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
SelectableRoleViewModel sr = auto.Map<SelectableRoleViewModel>(role);
```

gives me the following error message:

> AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

I am registering AutoMapper in Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

Then, in `AutoMapperProfile.cs`:

```
public class AutomapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutomapperProfile()
    {
        // This is not working:
        CreateMap<ApplicationRoleViewModel, SelectableRoleViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Selected, i => i.Ignore());

        // This is working:
        CreateMap<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserViewModel>();

        // Many more mappings, all working
    }
}
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: can you please register your automapper in configuration service like below and give it a try ?services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

Comment: @Chaodeng That made no difference. Still same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you specified seems to be correct.

I will just suggest to remove the `ForMember` method for properties with the same names as auto mapper handles it automatically:

```
CreateMap<ApplicationRoleViewModel, SelectableRoleViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Selected, i => i.Ignore());
```

The problem seems to be because you are not using the mapper right. Where have you registered the mapper? Is the registration happens before the map? Did you do it in the Startup? If you specify more code, it will be easier to help.

**UPDATE:**

After getting more code & info, the problem was that the map worked on a different object, `ApplicationRoleViewModel` and not `ApplicationRole`.

Comment: I am registering AutoMapper in Startup.cs like this: `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));`, and all my other mappings are working.

Comment: I have added a bit more information in my question.

Comment: @Stian Everything seems to be fine until now. Please show the map itself, are you doing the map in the right direction?

Comment: I have added the map in the question.

Comment: @Stian Which object does `await db.Roles.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` returns? I would offer you to move the await outside of the map and check if it works.

Comment: I moved the await outside, and confirmed it returned a valid `ApplicationRole`. The same error occured on the very next line of code, where the mapping is called.

Comment: @Stian The mapper maps `ApplicationRoleViewModel` and not `ApplicationRole`. This is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just to see a difference ;)

```
public static SelectableRoleViewModel ToSelectable(this ApplicationRoleViewModel model)
{
    return new SelectableRoleViewModel 
    {
       Id = model.Id,
       DisplayName = model.DisplayName
    };
}

// Usage
var selectable = applicationRole.ToSelectable();
```

- Type it once
- Perfectly testable
- Fully maintainable - supports all kinds of conversion/mapping
- Reduce amount of injected dependencies and abstractions (mapper)
- No extra dependencies on third party libraries